# Module works, but IC becomes extremely hot

Tags: power-supply, current, usb, integrated-circuit

I bought a Bluetooth-FM-LED Display-MP3 module and the PCB has a 64-pin TQFP IC. From a 5 V, 1 A adapter I supplied power through the connector on the PCB and it worked fine.

Later I connected the USB port (meant for a pen drive) to a 5 V, 3 A cellphone charger. It worked for less than a minute, suddenly the display blanked out, and the module stopped working.

I located a fusible resistor on the PCB and replaced it with a 0 Ω 0603 resistor. The module now works, but within 5 seconds, the IC becomes unbearably hot. I am sure that if I leave it connected to any 5 V source, then within 30 seconds, the IC will get fried.

I am trying to find out what blunder I committed. Experts on this forum may kindly answer these three questions and provide other relevant information.

1. Did connecting the USB port (meant for a pen drive) to a 5 V power supply damage the IC?
2. Did the 15 W cellphone charger supply too much current resulting in IC damage (sounds unlikely)?
3. Is it a combination of the above two?

Comment: Do you have a link to the module description?

Comment: What do you mean by "Later I connected the USB port (meant for a pen drive) to a 5V 3A cellphone charger", the USB input? How is a USB input meant for a pen drive? If you mean the output, then how did you connect it to a charger?

Comment: Bluetooth FM USB AUX Card MP3 Stereo Wireless TF Radio Audio Video Player Decoder Module
Link:
https://www.amazon.in/UT-Bluetooth-Transmitter-Multichannel-Amplifier/dp/B08C9KZCN7/ref=d_pd_sbs_sccl_2_1/261-5553304-6388852?pd_rd_w=q1bFw&content-id=amzn1.sym.02182ec1-65c5-4957-978b-1e230c9c10a7&pf_rd_p=02182ec1-65c5-4957-978b-1e230c9c10a7&pf_rd_r=3SRAAC6JY5EYVJNFK6X3&pd_rd_wg=shC1f&pd_rd_r=52de6b2f-555c-4737-9baa-00429eec9abe&pd_rd_i=B08C9KZCN7&psc=1

Answer (score 0):

A USB port intended to be connected to a pen drive is a USB **host** port, designed to produce 5 volts to power whatever is plugged into it. On the other hand, a USB **device** port is designed to accept 5 volts from the other device.

So you connected **host** port to **host** port, thus supplied power into a port intended to itself supply power. This, most likely, damaged something.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. That was my suspicion too. I connected 5V power to the USB host port, thinking the GND and 5V lines are anyway common between the host port and the 5V input connector and that's how the module worked for 30 seconds or so. But as you have mentioned, connecting host port to another host port damaged something in the IC.

Comment: @BalaChandar Solution: the USB charger should connect to the connector on the PCB that you originally used, and not to the USB port.